# Save the data of a text file in a arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem with my arraylist; indeed I need to fill my "list_Line" list with the data from my text file (example.txt) but after adding them to my list I can display my list but it seems empty... So did I fill in my list incorrectly or did I go about displaying its content incorrectly (I tried two different methods though) Please what do I have to do to be able to see the data in my text on the console?

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Search {
    private String path_Fichier;
    private static ArrayList<Search> list_Line = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader BR = null;


    public Search(String pathfichier) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.path_Fichier=pathfichier;

    }
    void charge(ArrayList list_Line) {
        FileReader fichier;
        try {
            fichier = new FileReader(this.path_Fichier);
            BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(fichier);
            String line;
            while((line=BR.readLine())!=null) {
                list_Line.add(line);
            }
            BR.close();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }
    void display() {
        System.out.println("before");
        System.out.println(list_Line);
        for (Search m: list_Line) {
            System.out.println(m);
            System.out.println("between");
        }
        for (int i=0; i<list_Line.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list_Line.get(i));
            System.out.println("between");
        }
        System.out.println("after");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Search s = new Search("exemple.txt");
        s.display();
    }

}
```

Comment: you never call `charge()`

Comment: I had tested with the first 'for' but not with the second and it works very well indeed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't even called charged() method. Call it and reply.